# Using a template so that each table's header row has purple background with white text

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, tex, pdflatex

I would like the first row of every table in all of my documents to have a purple background and white text.

I am converting a bunch of Markdown documents, most containing tables. I've been Using Pandoc to PDF with a TeX template called Eisvogel, which I have been modifying. Pandoc is using pdfTeX, I believe. (I am rather new to all of this so please forgive me in advance if this question ought to be elsewhere!)

The template: https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template/blob/master/eisvogel.tex

I am trying to achieve this (made in word) 
 [image: Desired table format]

This is the relevant section, which I have managed to amend slightly to make the white alternating row come first, and I've got the rule to become purple (take my word for it).

```
% tables

$if(tables)$
\definecolor{table-head-color}{HTML}{551a55} % Purple for the header row
\definecolor{table-row-color}{HTML}{F5F5F5}
\definecolor{table-rule-color}{HTML}{551a55}

%\arrayrulecolor{black!40}
\arrayrulecolor{table-rule-color}     % color of \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0ex} % thickness of midrule?
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0ex}      % thickness of \toprule, \bottomrule
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}     % spacing (padding)

$if(table-use-row-colors)$
\let\oldlongtable\longtable
\let\endoldlongtable\endlongtable
\renewenvironment{longtable}{
\rowcolors{3}{table-row-color!100}{}  % row color
% \rowcolor{table-head-color!100} % This produces an error
\oldlongtable} {
\endoldlongtable
\global\rownum=0\relax}
$endif$
$endif$
```

My markdown:

```
|Insert a | table | with | multiple | columns |
| --- |---|---|---|---|
|and some | content that will span several lines if possible because it's too large to fit | to go | with | it |
|This is | an | example | of such | A table |
```

resulting in:

[image]

Is there a way that I can set the 1st row of the table to have the properties mentioned above?

I have looked into Tabu, which has \taburowcolors which might be useful? The documentation gave me a headache!

Comment: Maybe you can have better luck asking on https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524382/template-options-to-change-the-background-colour-and-text-colour-of-all-tables

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a cross-network duplicate on a more suitable site has been posted (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524382/5764).